# Morphing from one svg to another

Tags: css, svg, css-animations

I have the same number of vertices but for whatever reason, my path's aren't morphing from one to another and I can't figure it out.

```html
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <defs>
   <style>.cls-1{fill:#669143;}</style>
  </defs>
  <title>world_pedals</title>
  <path class="cls-1" d="M142.88,53.79a6.56,6.56,0,0,0,3.89-.29c-.36-.07-.82-.38-.65-.64a.71.71,0,0,1,1-.11c.48.35-1.81-1.37-3.52-1.2,1.94-.48,4.1-.28,4.86.51s.84,1.3.46,1.88a2.55,2.55,0,0,1-2,.91C146.21,55,143.21,54.43,142.88,53.79Z" transform="translate(-141.35 -49.35)">
   <animate attributeName="d" dur="5s" to="M139.86,57.06c1.4.43,3.21-.93,3.67-1.2-.36-.08-.82-.38-.65-.64a.7.7,0,0,1,1.05-.12c.48.35-1.22-2.46-2.93-2.29a4.57,4.57,0,0,1,4.27,1.61c.68.71.84,1.3.46,1.88a2.53,2.53,0,0,1-2,.9C143,57.31,140.19,57.71,139.86,57.06Z" transform="translate(-132.24 -49.35)"/>
  </path>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/a926kgwf/

Comment: You need to have the same number and the same commands. Please take a look: first path second command is an arc a. Second path second command: a cubic bezier c

Comment: @enxaneta ok great, i didn't know they needed to be that exact